# Queue which wait until something happen

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to implement the queue, which waits for shared resource. When this resource is free, queue take the first added element and change the info in this resource. But when no, just wait. Is there any queues in concurrency library that can do this? Or i need to write my own queue? Or is there are a better way to do this? 
Thanks for help)

Comment: [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is your friend.

Comment: A [`CompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) might be a useful alternative to `BlockingQueue`, depending on what the producers and consumers are really doing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want two things.

1. A `BlockingQueue` instance (such as `ArrayBlockingQueue`) for your queue of tasks to perform on the resource.
2. A lock for the resource for your threads to wait on until the resource is available.

Your threads can then either take an item off the queue and wait on the resource lock, or wait on the resource lock and then try to take an item off the queue while holding that lock.

**Waiting and taking from the queue first is the easier design**, but your wording in the question makes it seem like you wish to do the opposite and wait on the resource lock first and then try to take from the queue.  That workflow is a little bit more complicated in that you should `poll()` from the queue (instead of `take()`'ing) and release your resource lock if you do not want to hold it if the queue is empty.

E.g.

1. Wait on resource lock
2. ... acquire resource lock
3. `poll` from queue
4. If queue was empty, release resource lock.
5. If queue was not empty, process queue item.
6. Release resource lock.
7. If queue was empty, sleep for a bit..?
8. Repeat.

Comment: The BlockingQueue provides [`take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take--) method that solves point 2.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am aware of the `take` method, especially as it is largely the reason for having a `BlockingQueue`, but the wording of the question seems to suggest there is another resource (separate from the queue) that needs to be waited on (e.g. a network connection or some such).  I could be wrong, the question is not particularly well worded, but this is my assumption and what my answer is based on.  E.g. A queue of items that needs to be sent to a network connection, that may also be being used by other threads etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. You're right, I need to more concrete disсribe the situation. There are different apps and one shared resource. Each app can change the info in the resource. My task is: i need to implement another app, which read and write (change) the resource. All information is changed in runtime and i need to store it in queue.
When resource is free, my app take the information from queue and change the information in resource.